# VS Code nodejs distant debugging: breakpoints are getting ignored

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I'm trying to set up a distant debug with VS Code on a node.js (7.1.0) project.

I launch my dev app with pm2:

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "name": "my-app-dev",
    "script": "app.js",
    "watch": true,
    "node_args": ["--inspect=9229", "--nolazy"],
    "ignore_watch": ["assets/images/", ".tmp/", ".git/"],
    "watch_options": {
      "usePolling": true
    }
  }]
}
```

this is the .vscode/launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node2",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "attach",
            "port": 9229,
            "address": "my.app.local",
            "restart": true,
            "diagnosticLogging": true,
            "sourceMaps": false
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start the debugger I successfully get attached `Debugger attached.`

The problem is my breakpoints are getting ignored: `Unverified breakpoint`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally found a solution by adding

```
"localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/api",
"remoteRoot": "/srv/www/my-app/api"
```

to my launch.json.

If someone can explains why its needed :o

Comment: Because the debugger has to map the file paths on the remote machine to file paths on the local machine